# Use Leiningen With Local M2 Repository

Tags: maven, clojure, leiningen

I want to compile a local jar into my clojure project, I can do this easily with the following

https://gist.github.com/stuartsierra/3062743

```
mkdir repo
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=local -DartifactId=bar \
    -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=bar.jar \
    -DlocalRepositoryPath=repo
```

But I have a continuous integration and build server (jenkins) that looks in ~/.m2.  How can I get leiningen to look in .m2???

Comment: What errors are you getting?  It should already be looking in ~/.m2 by default.

Comment: I was getting the Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate myapp/module__init.class or myapp/module.clj on classpath.

Comment: I tried installing my project in .m2 with "lein pom" and then "mvn install", which did copy the jars to ~/.m2 but the build still failed.  So eventually what I did was force the sibling libraries to be built in local_mvn_repo following http://nakkaya.com/2010/03/16/adding-custom-libraries-into-local-leiningen-repository/  Basically using building projects together is something im still nto totally sure I understand with Leiningen.  When to use the "nakkaya" trick, and when how to use ~/.m2.  Still fuzzy!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/sample.project.clj#L248), it looks like the key you're after is `:local-repo` in `project.clj`. Since you want to have different local repository locations on different servers, I would put this in a [profile](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/PROFILES.md) as opposed to directly in the `project.clj`.

Probably the best approach would be to create a `:user` profile in `~/.lein/profiles.clj` on whichever machine you want to change the location of the local repository:

```
{:user {:local-repo "repo"}}
```