# Clojure local maven repo with JNI dependency

Tags: java, maven, clojure, java-native-interface, dependencies

I am trying to create a local Maven repository for my Clojure/leiningen project, as for instance described here:

[Use Leiningen With Local M2 Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035529/use-leiningen-with-local-m2-repository)

I have also found out that more recent versions of Leiningen require the Maven command/goal to be "deploy:deploy-file" rather than "install:install-file". The problem I am facing is that the proprietary Java file/library I want to copy/deploy into a local Maven repository possesses a JNI-dependency in form of a dynamically linked C-library, such as "library.so" How do I accommodate this? Notice that this proprietary Java library I want to use does not possess a ready-made pom file with dependency management because it is ant-based. The Java library in question I wish to use in my Clojure project can be found here:

https://github.com/mkobos/lbfgsb_wrapper

and of course I want to set up my leiningen project + local Maven repo such that I can just run "lein deps" after suitable changes done to my project.clj

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Is great if you allready decided to use a deploy instad of install, your *so files you can use in an other project with maven-dependency-plugin similar as in my answer under https://stackoverflow.com/a/23421144/1811653 but use an other directory as target/classes.
Take care staff like this *.so you should deploy to the thidparty- with a releasenumber and not in snapshot- or releases-repository.