# How to package resources so that they can be accessed from other Maven artifacts?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I'm writing a system, which will consist of

1. proprietary, closed-source core component and
2. several plugins, which I intend to distribute with their source.

For now, these are simply Maven projects, let's say `myapp-core` (proprietary) and `myapp-plugin1` (distributed with the source code).

`myapp-plugin1` uses `myapp-core` in the following way. There is a main class in `myapp-plugin1`:

```
public class DisplayHouseholdsOnMapApp {
    public static void main(final String[] aArgs) {
        CoreApp app = new CoreApp();

        try {
            app.run(new MenuBarFactory(), new GlassPaneDisplay());
        } catch (final IOException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

`CoreApp` is defined in the `myapp-core` project, everything else (`MenuBarFactory`, `GlassPaneDisplay`) - in the `myapp-plugin1` project.

Inside `CoreApp.run` several things happen. Among other things, it tries to load data from files stored in `myapp-core/src/main/resources` folder.

When I launch `myapp-plugin1`, I get errors - classes defined in `myapp-core` cannot load files defined in that folder.

Now I read these data using constructs like

```
import com.google.common.io.Files;

final List<String> lines = Files.readLines(aFile, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

How can I read these files in `myapp-core` so that it works, when I use that project in `myapp-plugin1` ?

**Update 1:** The stack traces.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\XXXX.csv (Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131)
    at com.google.common.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:127)
    at com.google.common.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:117)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteSource$AsCharSource.openStream(ByteSource.java:404)
    at com.google.common.io.CharSource.getInput(CharSource.java:87)
    at com.google.common.io.CharSource.getInput(CharSource.java:63)
    at com.google.common.io.CharStreams.readLines(CharStreams.java:325)
    at com.google.common.io.Files.readLines(Files.java:747)
    at com.google.common.io.Files.readLines(Files.java:718)

18:19:29.896 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR r.a.c.p.impl.gui.PrimCityGlassPane - 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\XXX.csv (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0-ea]
    at com.google.common.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:127) ~[guava-15.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:117) ~[guava-15.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.io.ByteSource$AsCharSource.openStream(ByteSource.java:404) ~[guava-15.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.io.CharSource.getInput(CharSource.java:87) ~[guava-15.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.io.CharSource.getInput(CharSource.java:63) ~[guava-15.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.io.CharStreams.readLines(CharStreams.java:325) ~[guava-15.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.io.Files.readLines(Files.java:747) ~[guava-15.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.io.Files.readLines(Files.java:718) ~[guava-15.0.jar:na]
```

**Update 2:**

I tried to read the data using following code.

```
import com.google.common.io.Resources;
import com.google.common.base.Charsets;

final URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(aFile.getPath().substring
        ("src\\main\\resources\\".length()));
final List<String> lines = Resources.readLines(resource, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

But now, when I run `myapp-plugin1` I get following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:192)
    at com.google.common.io.Resources$UrlByteSource.<init>(Resources.java:79)
    at com.google.common.io.Resources$UrlByteSource.<init>(Resources.java:74)
    at com.google.common.io.Resources.asByteSource(Resources.java:68)
    at com.google.common.io.Resources.asCharSource(Resources.java:113)
    at com.google.common.io.Resources.newReaderSupplier(Resources.java:104)
    at com.google.common.io.Resources.readLines(Resources.java:154)
    at com.google.common.io.Resources.readLines(Resources.java:176)
```

Comment: 1. Can you post the stack trace when running from `myapp-plugin1`? I'm wondering if it's `FileNotFoundException`, `AccessDeniedException` or something else. 2. If you run `myapp-core` by itself, the files can be read?

Comment: @kuporific Ad 1): Yes, see update 1. 2) It's `FileNotFoundException`. 3) If I run `myapp-core` from inside the IDE, it works. I didn't try to run by launching the JAR file.

Comment: Resources shouldn't be read by using File you should use getResourcesAsStream("/..."), cause the folder `src/main/resources` is automatically copied into target/classes.

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks. I tried to read the data differently - see Update 2. But it still doesn't work. How can I read the file line-wise with minimum amount of code?

Comment: For Update 2: A `null` means `getResource` isn't finding the file. If the name of the file does not begin with a `/`, it will look for the file *relative to your current location/package*. If it does start with a `/`, it will look starting at the "root" of the jar. You probably want the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use one artifact in an other with a dependency but you ask for resources.
So here how you can do, use the maven-dependency-plugin with the goal: unpack, take care you unpack in a phase befor you need them. All the unpacked staff you can place in outputDirectory=target/classes 
Here an example with unpacking of two artifacts with the maven-dependency-plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org...</groupId>
                        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
                        <version>...</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>**/*.class,**/*.xml</includes>
                    </artifactItem>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>...</groupId>
                        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
                        <version>...</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>**/*.class</includes>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```